# Manipulating Text Field data, saving it in a local text file and showing it subsequently

Tags: flutter

I'm new to flutter and I'm just trying to tip my toes in it by trying to create a multipage app, that

- takes weight & height in text fields, both as variables,
- gets bmi, another variable by using: weight/(height^2)
- saves the bmi value as string in a local text file
- and subsequently, shows that saved value in the app

I'm having problem  with:

- getting the two text field values as variables
- calculating and saving bmi in the text file
- getting that text file value to show InApp

I tried many methods and solutions to get the values as variables and save & show the bmi I get from them, all showing errors.

I used the following code to save data locally,

```
  Future<String> get _localPath async {
    final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    print(directory.path);
    return (directory.path);
  }

  Future<File> get _localFile async {
    final path = await _localPath;
    return File("$path/BMI.txt");
  }

  Future<String> readContent() async {
    try {
      final file = await _localFile;
      String content = await file.readAsString();
      return content;
    } catch (e) {
      return "Error!";
    }
  }

  Future<File> writeContent() async {
    final file = await _localFile;
    return file.writeAsString("$data"); //this data value is not being saved
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    writeContent();
    readContent().then((String value){
      setState(() {
        data = value;
      });
    });
  }
```

And I used this code for the UI,

```
Container(
  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
  margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
  child: TextField(
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      labelText: "Enter Weight in KG",
    ),
   ),
  ),
Container(
  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
  margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
  child: TextField(
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      labelText: "Enter Height in Meters",
    ),
   ),
  ),
Padding(
 padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
  child: Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, right: 20),
          child: RaisedButton(
            child: Text("calculate BMI"),
            onPressed: () =>
              null,   //How can I calculate the BMI using this button?
            ),
        ),
        Container(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 4,
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
          child: Text(
            "Your Current BMI is : \t $data", //Shows Null, everytime
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          ),
        ),
      ],
  ),
),
Padding(
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
  child: RaisedButton(
    child: Text("Save"),
    onPressed: () =>    //how do I save the value in a local text file using this button?
      _displaySnackBar(context),
  ),
),
```

Here is my Full Code :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'BMI Calculator',
      home: HomePage(),
      routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
        "/home": (BuildContext context) => new HomePage(),
        "/info": (BuildContext context) => new UserInfo(),
      },
      theme: ThemeData(
        canvasColor: Colors.blueAccent,
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text("BMI Calculator"),
            backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
          ),
          body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                  child: Text(
                    "Home",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30),
                  child: RaisedButton(
                    child: Text("Enter User Info"),
                    onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("/info"),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                  child: RaisedButton(
                    child: Text("Exit"),
                    color: Colors.red,
                    onPressed: () => exit(0),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )),
    );
  }
}

class UserInfo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _UserInfo createState() => _UserInfo();
}

class _UserInfo extends State<UserInfo> {
  String data, x,y;
  double weight = 0.0, height = 0.0, bmi = 0.0;
  final _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  Future<String> get _localPath async {
    final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    print(directory.path);
    return (directory.path);
  }

  Future<File> get _localFile async {
    final path = await _localPath;
    return File("$path/BMI.txt");
  }

  Future<String> readContent() async {
    try {
      final file = await _localFile;
      String content = await file.readAsString();
      return content;
    } catch (e) {
      return "Error!";
    }
  }

  Future<File> writeContent() async {
    final file = await _localFile;
    return file.writeAsString("$data"); //this data value is not being saved
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    writeContent();
    readContent().then((String value){
      setState(() {
        data = value;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        key: _scaffoldKey,
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("BMI Calculator"),
          backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                child: Text(
                  "User Info",
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
                child: TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: "Enter Weight in KG",
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
                child: TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: "Enter Height in Meters",
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, right: 20),
                      child: RaisedButton(
                        child: Text("calculate BMI"),
                        onPressed: () =>
                            null,   //How can I calculate the BMI using this button?
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 4,
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                      child: Text(
                        "Your Current BMI is : \t $data", //Shows Null, everytime
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                child: RaisedButton(
                  child: Text("Save"),
                  onPressed: () =>    //how do I save the value in a local text file using this button?
                    _displaySnackBar(context),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, left: 20, right: 20),
                      child: RaisedButton(
                        child: Text("Home"),
                        color: Colors.blue,
                        onPressed: () =>
                            Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("/home"),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, left: 20, right: 20),
                      child: RaisedButton(
                        child: Text("Exit"),
                        color: Colors.red,
                        onPressed: () => exit(0),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
  _displaySnackBar(BuildContext context){
    final snackBar = SnackBar(
      content: Text(
        "Saved",
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      ),
    );
    _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(snackBar);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use `SharedPreferences`

code snippet

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();    
  height = await prefs.getDouble("height");
  weight = await prefs.getDouble("weight");
  print('height ${height}');
  print('weight ${weight}');
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'dart:math';

double height;
double weight;
double bmi;

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  //await prefs.setInt("initScreen", null);
  height = await prefs.getDouble("height");
  weight = await prefs.getDouble("weight");
  print('height ${height}');
  print('weight ${weight}');
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'BMI Calculator',
      home: HomePage(),
      routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
        "/home": (BuildContext context) => new HomePage(),
        "/info": (BuildContext context) => new UserInfo(),
      },
      theme: ThemeData(
        canvasColor: Colors.blueAccent,
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text("BMI Calculator"),
            backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
          ),
          body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                  child: Text(
                    "Home",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30),
                  child: RaisedButton(
                    child: Text("Enter User Info"),
                    onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("/info"),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                  child: RaisedButton(
                    child: Text("Exit"),
                    color: Colors.red,
                    onPressed: () => exit(0),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )),
    );
  }
}

class UserInfo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _UserInfo createState() => _UserInfo();
}

class _UserInfo extends State<UserInfo> {
  String data, x, y;
  final _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  final weightController = TextEditingController();
  final heightController = TextEditingController();

  double calculateBmi(double kg, double m) {
    return (kg / (m * m));
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      if (height != null && weight != null) {
        weightController.text = weight.toString();
        heightController.text = height.toString();
        data = calculateBmi(weight, height).toString();
        setState(() {});
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    weightController.dispose();
    heightController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        key: _scaffoldKey,
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("BMI Calculator"),
          backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                child: Text(
                  "User Info",
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
                child: TextField(
                  controller: weightController,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: "Enter Weight in KG",
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
                child: TextField(
                  controller: heightController,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: "Enter Height in Meters",
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, right: 20),
                      child: RaisedButton(
                          child: Text("calculate BMI"),
                          onPressed: () {
                            var kg = double.tryParse(weightController.text);
                            var m = double.tryParse(heightController.text);
                            data = calculateBmi(kg, m).toString();
                            setState(() {});
                          }),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 4,
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                      child: Text(
                        "Your Current BMI is : \t $data", //Shows Null, everytime
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                child: RaisedButton(
                    child: Text("Save"),
                    onPressed: () async {
                      SharedPreferences prefs =
                          await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
                      await prefs.setDouble(
                          "height", double.tryParse(heightController.text));
                      await prefs.setDouble(
                          "weight", double.tryParse(weightController.text));
                      _displaySnackBar(context);
                    }),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, left: 20, right: 20),
                      child: RaisedButton(
                        child: Text("Home"),
                        color: Colors.blue,
                        onPressed: () =>
                            Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("/home"),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, left: 20, right: 20),
                      child: RaisedButton(
                        child: Text("Exit"),
                        color: Colors.red,
                        onPressed: () => exit(0),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  _displaySnackBar(BuildContext context) {
    final snackBar = SnackBar(
      content: Text(
        "Saved",
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      ),
    );
    _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(snackBar);
  }
}
```

Comment: this works yes, but I wanted to save multiple BMI values, locally in the device, in a txt file.

Comment: You can use setStringList and getStringList https://pub.dev/documentation/shared_preferences/latest/shared_preferences/SharedPreferences/setStringList.html